# Kubernetes proxy route traffic to different sub services depending on request path

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, haproxy

Very simple and common case, i have 2 pods in cluser:

1. wordpress blog + mysql
2. nginx serving static web site

I want to show static web site when user load http://my-site.com and show blog when user will do http://my-site/blog 
Without kubernetes I would just use haproxy with rules analysing request path, I don't have so much experience in kubernetes to build it right way. 
Should 1 and 2 pods be a services as well?

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this may be to use an ingress resource. You could make the two services and then point at them from the ingress resource.

Reference: [Simple fanout using ingress resources.](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/#simple-fanout)